# Minimize redirection of http to https of Facebook buttons

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, redirect, pagespeed

PageSpeed recomendations is to minimize redirections.

Facebook redirect from http to https:
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php? -> https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
It's the same with like_box.php

I tried loading the JS all.js from https but with the same result.

Is there a way of loading the https version in the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to include the protocol in your link so use `//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?`
and the browser will add the protocol used for each case

Comment: I did that `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/...` still the same problem keeps happening.

Comment: Try to get and store the protocol in a var and then append it to the rest path. var protocol = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");